# asp question ADODB.Recordset and calling a procedure

Tags: asp-classic, adodb

I have to make an quick update on a legacy asp page never really having done anything with classical asp want to check if this is valid.

Can I do this:

```
set conn = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
conn.Open ("connection string info")

Set rsIdent = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

SQL = "EXEC procedureName @sParam = '" & someVariable & "'"
rsIdent.Open SQL, conn
iSome_ID = rsIdent.Fields("ident_value")
rsIdent.Close()
Set rsIdent = nothing
```

Where procedureName is a stored procedure that accepts a paramter, does some processing and returns a single record in a column called "ident_value"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Curtis: See [How to call SQL Server stored procedures from ASP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164485).